# Extract specific values from JSON using Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to figure out a way to display only the name and id from each object. I checked a lot of answers here already but I'm new to Python and I don't really know how to do this. This is my JSON file:

```
{"tags": [
    {
      "tagGroup": "Named Tags",
      "lastConfig": null,
      "notes": null,
      "color": "#ffcc33ff",
      "name": "tag 3",
      "lastConfigTS": null,
      "fwVersion": null,
      "id": "a4da22e0296b"
    },
    {
      "tagGroup": "Named Tags",
      "lastConfig": null,
      "notes": null,
      "color": "#ff00ccdd",
      "name": "tag 4",
      "lastConfigTS": null,
      "fwVersion": null,
      "id": "a4da22e04235"
    },
    {
      "tagGroup": "Named Tags",
      "lastConfig": null,
      "notes": null,
      "color": "#ff00cccc",
      "name": "tag 5",
      "lastConfigTS": null,
      "fwVersion": null,
      "id": "a4da22e02225"
    }
  ]}
```

This is my current code:

```
import json
    from pprint import pprint

    with open('tags.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    pprint(data["tags"][0]["id"])
```

I can get it to print only the first id, but I don't really know where to go from here. Is there a way to print only all of name and id values?

Comment: So the 0 in your pprint is the index. Increment that number to get to the other json indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterating through the list of dictionaries should do the trick for you.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('tags.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for tag in data["tags"]:
    pprint(tag["id"])
    pprint(tag["name"])
```

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I needed.